# Exception in console as Unable to find a link which is already clicked in Selenium

Tags: drop-down-menu

Im trying to select an option from the dropdown list but it doesnt get selected. The exception that I get is:

> Unable to find element with link text == Open account

when this link is already clicked and the dropdown values are in the next page.
The code is:

```
<select class='comp_select' name='IS_CONSENT_TO_SHARE'><option  value=''>Select</option><option value='YES'>Yes</option><option value='NO'>No</option></select>
```

I tried:

```
Select dropdown1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("Consent")));
        dropdown1.selectByValue("YES");
```

also tried with `selectByvisibletext("YES")` but it doesn't  select any value.

Comment: I do see you are using By.name("Consent")   you have it named name='IS_CONSENT_TO_SHARE'

Comment: Ys this worked.Thanks Josh.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! I added the answer so you can close your question.  Best of luck in your automation :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class='comp_select' name='IS_CONSENT_TO_SHARE'><option  value=''>Select</option><option value='YES'>Yes</option><option value='NO'>No</option></select>
```

You have name ='IS_CONSENT_TO_SHARE'

change that to `name = 'Consent'` so it matches your selector `By.name("Consent")`